# Trying to get my dot-to-dot game to 'snap to' the closest dot

Tags: javascript

I know it's a simple calculation, but can you help me?

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhillipSenn/JLccR/2/).

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var radius = 4;

for (x=radius; x<canvas.width-radius; x+=50) {
    for (y=radius; y<canvas.height-radius; y+=50) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        context.stroke();
    }
}
$('canvas').click(canvasClicked);

function canvasClicked(e) {
    var x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
    var y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    context.stroke();
};
```

I'm trying to identify which cirlce is the one that's closest to where the user clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is here:

```
var newX = Math.round(x/50)*50 + radius;
var newY = Math.round(y/50)*50 + radius;
x = newX;
y = newY;
```

Here's the fiddle for that:
http://jsfiddle.net/avall/vtEER/1/

You round the clicked position to the resolution of your dot generator;

Oh, and you should watch out for edge points - didn't do `ifs` for that

Comment: Beautiful!  Thank you very much indeed.  I teach in a computer lab, and I'm going to display this dot-to-dot game while I lecture to give students a common game that they can play.

Comment: I hope your students will enjoy the game you develop :).

Comment: I edited my fiddle because your x and y coordinates had to be shifted by radius too. Now it works to the single pixel.